# INSERT INTO SELECT with a variable

Tags: php

i have two functions nearly identical :

```
public function plusOneAgree($commentId){
    $req = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO flagOpinions (opinionId, subscriberLogin, forumSubjectsId, subscriberId) SELECT id, login, idForum, agree FROM opinions WHERE id = ?');
    $req->execute([ 
        $commentId 
    ]);
}

public function plusOneDisagree($commentId){
    $req = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO flagOpinions (opinionId, subscriberLogin, forumSubjectsId, subscriberId) SELECT id, login, idForum, disagree FROM opinions WHERE id = ?');
    $req->execute([ 
        $commentId 
    ]);
}
```

There is only the name of column before FROM that is different.
How can i write only one function, if it is possible, please?
Thank you.

Comment: The language in your question is not SQL, as the tag implies. What language is it? Please add the correct tag too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function plusOne($commentId, $agree){
    @sql = 'INSERT INTO flagOpinions (opinionId, subscriberLogin, forumSubjectsId, subscriberId) SELECT id, login, idForum, '.$agree.' FROM opinions WHERE id = ?'
    $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $req->execute([ 
        $commentId 
    ]);
}
```

use with `plusOne($commentID,"agree")` or `plusOne($commentID,"disagree")`

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no knowledge of PHP but you might do something like blow. Add another parameter $agree to determine whether you need agree or disagree in your sql statement. Pass 1 if you need agree or anything else for disagree.

```
  public function plusOneAgree($commentId,$agree){
    if ($agree==1)
    {
        $req = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO flagOpinions (opinionId, subscriberLogin, forumSubjectsId, subscriberId) SELECT id, login, idForum, agree FROM opinions WHERE id = ?');
    }
    else
    {    
        $req = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO flagOpinions (opinionId, subscriberLogin, forumSubjectsId, subscriberId) SELECT id, login, idForum, disagree FROM opinions WHERE id = ?');
    }
    
        $req->execute([ 
            $commentId 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: `$commentId.$agree` these should be separated by a ',', not a '.'., And `$agree=1` is an assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is so simple i am ashmed.

Comment: There is nothing to be ashamed in learning. you are most welcome.